# Assign 2 vals in class init block using function which returns Pair

Tags: kotlin

Given a class like this:

```
class Test {
  val A: Car
  val B: Truck

  init {
    (A, B) = returnCarAndTruck()
  }

  fun returnCarAndTruck() = Pair(Car(), Truck())
}
```

I want to intialize the vals for A and B using a function which returns a pair but it doesn't seem to work unless I define the vals inside the init block. This means I no longer have reference to them correct? Is it possible to intialize these 2 with a Pair?

Comment: we can't i also tried doing this, you've to use first and second property of pair and do it in seperate lines!

Comment: ugh... yea I had that working which seems very un-kotlin like. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

The best we have for what you're looking for is the following:

```
class Test {
    val A: Car
    val B: Truck

    init {
        val (a, b) = returnCarAndTruck()
        A = a
        B = b
    }

    fun returnCarAndTruck() = Pair(Car(), Truck())
}
```